# How to show the uploaded file in File picker in Moodle?

Tags: moodle, filepicker

Hi I am working with **Moodle 2.9.1**. Here I have a form for upload a question and an answer file. I successfully upload the answer file to a location and inserted the question text and answer file name in database.

Now I want to edit the question, while editing the question the already uploaded file will be shown in the `file picker` area.

```
How can I show the uploaded file in filepicker area??
```

For text editor  I can use

```
$mform->addElement('editor', 'desc', get_string('description'));     
$mform->setDefault('desc', array('text'=>$defaulttext));
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

The filepicker element is used for uploading a single one-off file, that will be processed (and then, usually, discarded). If you are wanting a file that remains part of the Moodle storage and will reappear when you reopen the form, then you should use a filemanager (and restrict to a single file, if needed).

There are details in the Moodle docs about how to use this https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Using_the_File_API_in_Moodle_forms#filemanager (including re-populating the 'draft files' area when you load the form).